# How to solve the issue of the downloaded Excel files presenting the error?

Tags: python, excel, beautifulsoup

I am trying to download files from the link as seen in the code. However, I get the following error when I open the downloaded files. How would I go about solving the issue?

[image]

Please see the code below:

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Python 3.x
from urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve, quote
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import urllib

headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"}
resp = requests.get("https://www.elections.on.ca/en/resource-centre/elections-results.html#accordion2022ge")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"html.parser")

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(link)
    if 'xlsx' in link['href']:
#        print(link['href'])
        url="https://www.elections.on.ca/en/resource-centre/elections-results.html#accordion2022ge"+link['href']
#    print(url)
        file= url.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]+".xlsx"
        print(file)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Please see the code below:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
#    print(link)
    if 'xlsx' in link['href']:
        print(link['href'])
        url="https://www.elections.on.ca/"+link['href']
#        print(url)
        file= url.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]+".xlsx"
#        print(file)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file)
```